# change the layout of my chrome browser? Specifically the space above the tabs

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

I'm running Chrome (recent version) in a Mac OSX.

So as a LAMP stack/software developer I have the requisite 117 open tabs in Chrome, and also I occasionally need to move the window around as I usually have 72 applications running.  It's part of the "programmer's code of honor " (or torture).

So, this is a minor detail but is there any way to double the window margin above the Chrome tabs for my "gotta move it now" attitude?  If so that would be great and I could stop playing microsurgeon ;)

Comment: I would guess this area is controlled at the OS level. I may be wrong, but that's just my first guess. What OS are you running? Please add this information to the original question as it is necessary to the solving of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any way to change the layout of that part of the window. Even Chrome themes can't modify it; they can only change colors and patterns.

If it helps any, there's a somewhat larger draggable area above the "new tab" button, right around here:

[image]